# How to continue a command in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, try-catch

I am making a GUI to send emails with attachments using Tkinter and Win32 lib. There are times when attachments will not be fed into the folder for some Id's. During such circumstances I want to capture the error and skip the ID and move to the next ID for which attachment might be available. I am able to capture the error using the below, but am stuck in skipping part of the code. I tried pass but it just opens the mail without attachment completely ignoring the error. Basically I want to make a list of all captured errors and feed it into a dataframe to request attachments.

For the below eg send(x) is just to provide a vague idea about the code it's not an actual function

```
For x in id_list:
   Try:
     Send(x)
   Except python.com_error as error:
      Print("attachment not found")
```

Comment: Can you provide definition of `Send`, which you do use in snippet?

Comment: Hi Daweo sorry for the confusion Send(x) is just an example to give an idea  not an actual function